# How to get exactly time when parse json

Tags: c#, json.net

I have Json with item like below:

```
{
 "Id": 3355211,
 "TimeStamp": "2018-08-13T00:16:06.47",
}
```

I want access TimeStamp so I call

```
   string _time= item.TimeStamp;
```

So _time return  `{8/13/2018 12:16:06 AM}` . I want get exactly `2018-08-13T00:16:06.47`. How can I do that ?

Comment: You want to `TimeStamp` property to be a `string` instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: _How_ did you "parse json"?

Comment: if you are using Datetime to parse json please check your server Datetime format. usually it convert into system datetime format.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample code and using Newtonsoft.Json

```
void Main()
{
   var s = "{ \"Id\": 3355211, \"TimeStamp\": \"2018-08-13T00:16:06.47\", }";
   JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(s).Dump();
 }
public class JsonClass{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

And the output will look like,

[image]